# How do I add a favicon to Single Spa?

Tags: webpack, favicon, html-webpack-plugin, single-spa

I've spent some time trying to find a way to add a favicon to [Single Spa](https://single-spa.js.org/) application, believe it or not :). I couldn't find anything in the framework [documentation](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/getting-started-overview). There are bits and pieces about static assets but it didn't really help me much. I eventually realised it's to do with the Webpack configuration. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are still struggling here is the easiest and most elegant way I've found. **HtmlWebpackPlugin** solves this by providing a favicon property. Documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options). If you are using Sing Spa 5.x the HtmlWebpackPlugin plugin is already a dependency. Simply update parameters the root-config application webpack.config.js file with the following. Path is relative to the webpack.config.js directory.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    favicon: "./[path-to-your-file]/favicon.ico"
})
```

Then add the following line in your index.ejs file head section.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Clear your browser cache and you should be good to go.

Comment: Great catch! Exactly what I was looking for. For me the link tag needed a slash in front of the favicon. `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">`

Comment: @Stefanie Glad it helped. It depends on where your favicon.ico file is located in the file system. I guess in your case the file was in the root.

Comment: I did not need to change the `index.ejs` file in order for it to work. Thanks.